# Join query in hibernate search

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I want to write a lucene query like

```
" from activity where metaentityByEntity.id in(select metaentityByEntity.id from userentity where user.id=1)"
```

My domain classes are:

```
public class Activity implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private Date timeStamp;
    private User user;
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private Metaentity metaentityByEntity;
}

public class Userentitydetail implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private Date timeStamp;
    private Metaentity metaentityByEntity;
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private User user;
    private Metaentity metaentityByProjectId;
    private byte unfollow;
    private Byte isAssociated;
}
```

But how to write lucene query which will search from multiple indexes? basically I am doing hibernate search.

Thanks.

Comment: You example does not seem to be consistent and the Search configuration is not complete either. If you really need a join and it looks similar to what you post in HQL, then I recommend doing a HQL query, especially since you are not using any of the fulltext search functionality.

Comment: @Hardy Basically i want to write a lucene query which looks like above hibernate query.

Answer (score 2):

Lucene is not a relational database, so the short answer is you shouldn't try doing joins; your specific use case happens to be implementable because your query can be greatly simplified.

Just create a query on the field which is following the link:

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
    .buildQueryBuilder()
    .forEntity( Activity.class )
    .get();

Query query = queryBuilder.keyword()
    .onField( "metaentityByEntity.user.id" )
    .ignoreAnalyzer()
    .matching( 1 )
    .createQuery();
```

You'll have to adjust some details as you omitted some mapping details; for example it might need to be

```
.matching( "1" )
```

instead.

Comment: In hibernate search can i do it using @FieldBridge annotation. means In activity table use "@FieldBridge on set<UserdeEntityDetail>".